# How to specify output directory for .exe in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, openfiledialog, process.start

I am developing wpf application in C#. I have one button on which I am browsing file system through Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog. There is one submit button on which I am calling the Process.Start() to run .exe on grib file. The exe generate the .csv files for me successfully. First I browse the file system, select the file and then I click on submit button. My application execution path is D:\Projects\ApiRouting\ApiRouting\bin\Debug. There is one folder in my application at D:\Projects\ApiRouting\ApiRouting\Files. When I select the file from path D:\Projects\ApiRouting\ApiRouting\Files and click on submit button then the .csv files get generated at D:\Projects\ApiRouting\ApiRouting\Files which is correct. When I select the file from D:\Documents and click on submit button the .csv files are generated at D:\Documents. My code to run .exe is as follows

```
 public static void GenerateCsvFile(string fileName)
        {

                System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                startInfo.FileName = @"C:\ndfd\degrib\bin\degrib.exe";
                startInfo.Arguments = @"" + fileName + "" +" -C -msg 1 -Csv";
                startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                process.Start();
                process.WaitForExit();
                process.Close();

                System.Diagnostics.Process process1 = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo1 = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo1.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                startInfo1.FileName = @"C:\ndfd\degrib\bin\degrib.exe";
                startInfo1.Arguments = @"" + fileName + "" + " -C -msg all -nMet -Csv";
                startInfo1.UseShellExecute = true;
                process1.StartInfo = startInfo1;
                process1.Start();
                process1.WaitForExit();
                process1.Close();

        }


private void BrowseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            safeFileName = string.Empty;
            // Create OpenFileDialog
            Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

            // Set filter for file extension and default file extension
            //dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt";
            //dlg.Filter = "Zip Files|*.zip*";
            dlg.Multiselect = false;
            // Display OpenFileDialog by calling ShowDialog method
            Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

            // Get the selected file name and display in a TextBox
            if (result == true)
            {
                FileNameTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
                // Open document
                string fileName = dlg.FileName;
                safeFileName = dlg.SafeFileName;
                App.ZipFileSafeName = safeFileName;

                FileNameTextBox.Text = fileName;
                App.ZipFileName = fileName;
            }

            //dlg.InitialDirectory = @"D:\Projects\ApiRouting\ApiRouting\bin\Debug";
            //dlg.FileName = @"D:\Projects\ApiRouting\ApiRouting\bin\Debug\Pacificwind.grb";
            //dlg.Reset();
        }
```

When the user selects the file from any location of file system I copy that file at D:\Projects\ApiRouting\ApiRouting\Files and then run the .exe. So GenerateCsvFile method always has the fileName parameter value D:\Projects\ApiRouting\ApiRouting\Files\xyz.grb. So why my application is generating the .csv file at D:\Documents when I select the grib file from D:\Documents and why it is generating the .csv file at D:\Projects\ApiRouting\ApiRouting\Files when I select the .csv file from D:\Projects\ApiRouting\ApiRouting\Files ?

Comment: your escaping seems "odd"... another point: the code you show doesn't have anything to do with the problem you describe (OpenFileDialog)... what is the value of the parameter `fileName` when the above code is executed (check via Debugger)?

Comment: @Yahia, i think he have problems with understanding how degrib.exe works and where it creates result, not OpenFileDialog problems

Comment: filename always has value D:\Projects\ApiRouting\ApiRouting\Files\xyz.grb

Comment: What if you did this `startInfo1.Arguments = @"" + fileName + "" + " -C -msg all -nMet -Csv > outputfile.csv"`? This should pipe the output from `degrib.exe` into a file of your choice.

Comment: @NickW what is outputfile.csv? If it is a path can rewrite this command with with some temporary path ?

Comment: `outputfile.csv` was just to indicate the concept. You could change that line instead to: `startInfo1.Arguments = @"" + fileName + "" + " -C -msg all -nMet -Csv > " + fileName + ".csv"`

Comment: Scratch that, I don't think piping the output will help in this case. You could try setting the `WorkingDirectory` of `startInfo`. I think you could set it to `new FileInfo(fileName).DirectoryName`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`degrib.exe` seems to be writing its output to whatever the working directory is. Your options are

1. Figure out if there is an argument to `degrib` that allows you to specify where the output CSV files should end up.
2. Set the `WorkingDirectory` of the `startInfo` to the directory you would like them written to. You could do this with: `startInfo.WorkingDirectory = new FileInfo(fileName).DirectoryName;` This should ensure that the files are written to the same directory as the GRB file.

Comment: Thanks for your continuous support from last 2 days. Finally you have solved my problem. Now everything is working fine.Thanks buddy